# Admin error: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2

I'm getting this error and it is keeping me busy all day. I get it when I log in on the admin page. After going back to /admin I get the same error. The magento version is 1.7.x

things I have undertaken so far (among the things I still can remember)

- clear browser cache
- clear cache (db & files)
- clear sessions
- clear locks
- execute

  ```
  TRUNCATE mage_dataflow_batch_export ; TRUNCATE mage_dataflow_batch_import ; TRUNCATE mage_log_customer ; TRUNCATE mage_log_quote ; TRUNCATE mage_log_summary ; TRUNCATE mage_log_summary_type ; TRUNCATE mage_log_url ; TRUNCATE mage_log_url_info ; TRUNCATE mage_log_visitor ; TRUNCATE mage_log_visitor_info ; TRUNCATE mage_log_visitor_online ; TRUNCATE mage_report_event ;
  ```

  the XXXXX is for customer's privacy

```
    There has been an error processing your request

    SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'

    Trace:
    #0 /var/www/vhosts/xxxxxx/httpdocs/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(111): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
    #1 /var/www/vhosts/xxxxx/httpdocs/lib/Zend/Db/Statement.php(300): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
    #2 /var/www/vhosts/xxxxxx/httpdocs/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
    #3 /var/www/vhosts/xxxxxxxx/httpdocs/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `adminnotification_inbox` (`severity`, `date_added`, `title`, `description`, `url`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)', Array)
    #4 /var/www/vhosts/xxxxxx/httpdocs/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(419): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `adminnotification_inbox` (`severity`, `date_added`, `title`, `description`, `url`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)', Array)
    #5 /var/www/vhosts/xxxxxxxx/httpdocs/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(574): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('INSERT INTO `adminnotification_inbox` (`severity`, `date_added`, `title`, `description`, `url`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)', Array)
    #6 /var/www/vhosts/xxxxxxx/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/AdminNotification/Model/Resource/Inbox.php(120): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->insert('adminnotification_inbox', Array)
    #7 /var/www/vhosts/xxxxxxx/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/AdminNotification/Model/Inbox.php(118): Mage_AdminNotification_Model_Resource_Inbox->parse(Mage_AdminNotification_Model_Inbox, Array)
    #8 /var/www/vhosts/xxxxxx/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/AdminNotification/Model/Feed.php(97): Mage_AdminNotification_Model_Inbox->parse(Array)
    #9 /var/www/vhosts/xxxxxx/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/AdminNotification/Model/Observer.php(50): Mage_AdminNotification_Model_Feed->checkUpdate()
    #10 /var/www/vhosts/xxxxxxxx/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1338): Mage_AdminNotification_Model_Observer->preDispatch(Varien_Event_Observer)
    #11 /var/www/vhosts/xxxxxx/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1317): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Mage_AdminNotification_Model_Observer, 'preDispatch', Varien_Event_Observer)
    #12 /var/www/vhosts/xxxxxx/httpdocs/app/Mage.php(447): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('controller_action_predispatch', Array)
    #13 /var/www/vhosts/xxxxx/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(528): Mage->dispatchEvent('controller_action_predispatch', Array)
    #14 /var/www/vhosts/xxxxxxx/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php(160): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->preDispatch()
    #15 /var/www/vhosts/xxxxxx/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(408): Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action->preDispatch()
    #16 /var/www/vhosts/xxxxxx/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
    #17 /var/www/vhosts/xxxxxx/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http)
    #18 /var/www/vhosts/xxxxxxx/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
    #19 /var/www/vhosts/xxxxx/httpdocs/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
    #20 /var/www/vhosts/xxxxx/httpdocs/index.php(89): Mage->run('', 'store')
```

I find 0 and PRIMARY odd in this case...
thanks
Thomas

Comment: All those truncates you did are the shotgun method in the hopes a pellet hits the target over your shoulder from a ricochet. The issue is with the `adminnotification_inbox` table which means that some notification from Magento or a third party module vendor suffered a double entry infarction when it was added to the admin **System Notifications** mailbox. Make sure you always do a database backup before doing any database maintenance. Being able to restore from a mildly broken database backup that can be repaired is "Golden".

Comment: A yes, sorry guys, I also did some research on the adminnotification_inbox. But I was under the impression that, since I disabled the AdminNotification, it couldn't be the source of the problem. I will look into it this morning and report back. thanks Fiasco Labs, yes I always make Database backups. Indeed, it is Golden

Comment: The only way to properly **completely** disable a module is to look in the appropriate module `.xml` file in app/etc/modules and change the value between the `active` tags to `false`, then pray there are no dependencies. The disable in `system config advanced` only disables output, doesn't prevent table access. If any foreign keys exist to that table, they will result in a check fault as well. Kudos on the db backup.

Comment: @FiascoLabs . Yes I do backups regulary. But in this case something went incredibly wrong. Not only the auto-increment of the 'adminnotification_inbox' is gone but every table that originally had a primary key with a-i has lost the a-i!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like `auto-increment` is ***disabled*** on the `primary-key` of that table.

That or the `data-type` is wrong.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: This answer is actually the closest. However, auto increment is most likely enabled, but at max integer value, rolling over to -1 but never getting altered. Easiest way to restore the table is to drop it and recreate the definition without the AUTO_INCREMENT table property.

Comment: @RKT-JoinMageStackDay2015, technically there was no question to answer. OP made a statement, I responded with 2 possible causes to the error posted.

Comment: @thomas-coucke, can you provide a dump of the table structure?

Comment: Ok guys this is what was going on. Before I posted the question here I had emptied the adminnotification table but with the same error. Now I have emptied it and enabled the a-i of the primary key. Now the admin works fine! However, during my search for a solution I didn't mind the adminnotification table because I switched of the adminnotification in the backend (config->advanced->disable). So how did the table get populated? In anyway, thank you all for the thinking and proposed solutions!

Comment: @DanielSmith : but you really need to elaborate your answer. If I was you, then I will surely make a comment rather than a one sentence answer. :-) In first read, it gave me a "comment" feeling. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 1):

This error seem to have something to do with `AdminNotification`

So take a look at db tables

- `adminnotification_inbox`

Answer (score 0):

Issue fixed

1. `auto-increment` is disabled on the `primary-key` of log_visitor_info table.
2. change `default` to `none` and `attribute` to `empty`